# set.union() complains that it has no argument when passing in a generator

Tags: python, ipython, generator

This is from page 204 of Python for Data Analysis by Wes Mckinney

```
genre_iter = (set(x.split('|')) for x in movies.genres)
genres = sorted(set.union(*genre_iter))
```

This code works perfectly when using the `%paste` method in IPython. The code also works perfectly when run in Python shell. However, when I type the second line into IPython directly, without the `%paste` method

```
genres = sorted(set.union(*genre_iter))
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: descriptor 'union' of 'set' object needs an argument
```

this appears to be a bug, unless there is a feature of IPython that I am still unaware of.

Comment: [This is not the site](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues) you are [looking for](https://launchpad.net/ipython)

Comment: @PenguinCoder: No bug here at all, just a misunderstanding about the nature of generators and iterators.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have exhausted the generator. Re-define it before using it again:

```
genre_iter = (set(x.split('|')) for x in movies.genres)
genres = sorted(set.union(*genre_iter))
```

In python, once you have looped over all the elements of an iterator, you cannot loop over the iterator again (it is now empty).

Because the `genre_iter` iterator is empty, you are not passing *any* arguments to `set.union()` and it thus complains:

```
>>> set.union()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'union' of 'set' object needs an argument
```

Just to be explicit: you did not find a bug in ipython. You can reproduce the same issue in a regular python prompt.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `*` before the `genre_iter`? I was trying to figure out a similar code in a GitHub repo. Another Python guide mentioned that it is for unpacking sets for union API. Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/100297); it unpacks `genre_iter` into separate arguments for the `set.union()` method.